# Bootstrap website loads zoomed on iphone

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, meta-tags

We have built a website using Bootstrap 3.3. The website appears fine On Desktops and Tablets and on Android devices, but on **Iphones** it seems to load the website zoomed.
i did put the below meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

If i put `initial-scale=1` or `minimum-scale = 1` or `maximum-scale = 1`, the website loads zoomed on both iphone and android. If i do not have them it loads zoomed only on iphone.

Can anyone suggest what the issue is and how i can resolve it

Answer (score 0):

[how to use viewport](https://emiliocobos.net/meta-viewport-html/)

The page is not responsive ... it is a real shame! Google it will take into account and will penalize your rankings

Comment: Is there an English version of the site? Client specifically requested to remove the responsiveness.

Comment: Your client specifically wants to make it harder to use on a mobile device...? Are they insane? Mobile is the biggest source of traffic on the web!

Comment: You should try to convince your client to make their site responsive as well... bcz most of the people now a days prefer to access web from smart phones.. it will be helpful for them..

Comment: Trust me @MuhammadUsman - i did a lot of convincing. I had to revert the responsiveness features based on clients decision.

Answer (score 0):

English info about the viewport meta tag

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Naviego is right. I know by your comment that your client wants to have the responsiveness removed but whats the reason? He is right that google will penalize your ranking if your website is not mobile friendly. You should check it out..

- https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly

I tested it for you, and it says that your content is too big for a mobile screen, as you can scroll to the right.

Comment: Thank you for the viewport link. Do you recommend to have multiple viewports ?

Comment: I recommend a responsive website/application always. I don't see a valid or good reason why your client don't want a responsive website, unless your asking a too much money for it. So to answer your question, I dont use the multiple viewports, only `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`